# How to reset tags to default in OneNote 2016 (Office 365)

Tags: office365, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2016

Not sure how my tags got customized, maybe from some template that got loaded to our machines or some notebook with explicit custom tags, but I somehow lost the defaults which I actually prefer.

I went and tried to delete `preferences.dat` as suggested elsewhere for previous versions, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to reset the tags by running this registry script to delete the custom tags. Create a text file, copy the below, save as `reset-tags.reg` and run it to reset tags back to defaults.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\OneNote\Custom NoteTags]
```

Comment: This worked for me and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This solved the problem for me as well. You can just delete the "Custom NoteTags" folder  in regedit.

Answer (score 1):

I took a fresh install registry from another PC and imported in my PC. Works perfect. See the registry files uploaded in below Google Drive link. Steps:

1. Open regedit in search console. Go to Computer/HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/Office/16.0/OneNote/Custom NoteTags
2. Export current registry for folder CustomNoteTags (keep as backup)
3. Import default registry settings from file in Google Drive link (RegEdit -> File -> Import)

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1CHSwYXDXuXRj9p-IgpcrfXrRWamdiubg?usp=sharing